# Type safe enums and scoping auxiliary functions

Tags: c++, c++11, syntactic-sugar

When using enums, I usually have a few auxiliary methods associated with them. For C-style enums, I usually did this:

```
namespace Colour {
    enum Enum { RED, BLUE, GREEN };
    string to_string(Enum);
    Enum from_string(string const&);
}
```

C++11 enum classes force you to use annoying prefixes:

```
enum class Colour { RED, BLUE, GREEN };
string colour_to_string(Enum);
Enum colour_to_string(string const&);
```

What are my options for getting type safety, with the namespace-like scoping?

Comment: What's your issue with enum classes?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Those "annoying prefixes" are scopes, and are part of the motivation for C++11 enums.

Comment: @Rapptz: That I cant do Colour::to_string/Colour::from_string.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I shall read the Paper about enum classes, because I find them really limiting. For example you cant define operator| as convineintly as for classes or ordinary enums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to go:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum class Colors{ RED, BLUE, GREEN };

struct myRedStruct{
    bool operator==(const Colors& c)const{
        if(c == Colors::RED)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};

namespace ColorsUtils {
    using namespace std;

    template <typename ColorComparable>
    string to_string(const ColorComparable& c){
        if(c == Colors::RED)
            return "red";
        return "not red";
    }
    Colors from_string(string const&);
}

int main() {
    Colors c = Colors::BLUE;
    const auto& s = ColorsUtils::to_string(c);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    myRedStruct mrs;
    const auto & s2 = ColorsUtils::to_string(mrs);
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

which is pretty much the same thing you would do with any other user-defined type. Try the above code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f56613617aa0905dd205f43ce9638771-72f1b4de714fd92d7b53b2e51b310d82). Notice that in the example you can "convert" to string any equal comparable type.

Comment: I've decided to go for this type of a solution, though for my app, the ColorComparable is a bit of an overkill. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What are my options for getting type safety, with the namespace-like scoping?

This is type safe:

```
enum class Colour { RED, BLUE, GREEN };
string colour_to_string(Colour);
Colour from_string(string const&);
```

You can decide to put everything inside a namespace. The enum's type behaves like any other user defined type. However, whereas the first method needs no type information (it could be called `enum_to_string`), the second one needs either a name involving the type of the enum, a namespace, or to be a function template. This is because you cannot overload based on return type. So, you can put everything in a namespace, and take advantage of argument dependent look-up when using the enum-to-string method:

```
namespace colour
{
  enum class Colour { RED, BLUE, GREEN };
  string to_string(Colour);
  Colour from_string(string const&);
}

int main()
{
  using colour::Colour;
  Colour c{Colour::RED};
  string s = to_string(c); // ADL kicks in
  Colour c2 = colour::from_string("RED"); // no ADL, must specify namespace
}
```

Comment: the more i see it, the more I don't get the point, so I will ask: why on earth you want to extract the "real" value of any given ENUM ? what is the point of an ENUM at that point ?

Comment: @user2485710 You mean the underlying value? I don't think anyone here is trying to do that. The question is about conversion to and from strings, and how to organize the namespaces.

Comment: @jogojapan how you explain this `string to_string(Colour);` then ?

Comment: @user2485710 The idea, as far as I understand, is to convert the value `Colour::red` into the string `"red"`, e.g. for pretty-printing purposes. This can be useful in debug or log messages, when printing the values of enum variables.

Comment: @user2485710 ehm, it wants to get a string representation of an enum's value? That is a very common use-case.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the C++11 `enum class` the way you suggested, including the namespace, indeed you will need two qualifiers to access them: `Colour::Colour::RED`, which you may find annoying.

However, I don't think it is useful – neither for type safety nor for any other reason – to put the `from_string` and `to_string` functions into a namespace.

`to_string()` applies to many types, not only `Colour`. In fact, since C++11, there is even `std::to_string`, which you can apply to various built-in types to transform them into `std::string`. It makes sense to simply extend that notion to cover user-defined types:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(const T arg)
{ return std::to_string(arg); }

template <>
std::string to_string(const Color c)
{
  switch (c)
    {
    case Color::red:
      return "red";
    case Color::green:
      return "green";
    case Color::blue:
    default:
      return "blue";
    }
}
```

You can then use `to_string(42)` as well as `to_string(Color::red)`, and this is completely type-safe (as type-safe as any function overload / template specialization).

Similarly for `from_string`:

```
template <typename T>
T from_string(const std::string &str);

template <>
Color from_string<Color>(const std::string &str)
{
  if (str == "red")
    return Color::red;
  else if (str == "green")
    return Color::green;
  else if (str == "blue")
    return Color::blue;
  else
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid color");
}
```

I have provided only the implementation for `Color`, but it would be straight-forward to add it for other types.

Using this is type-safe and requires the explicit specification of `Color` (as template argument or scope qualifier) only where necessary, without duplication:

```
int main()
{
  Color c = Color::red;

  std::cout << to_string(c) << std::endl;
  c = from_string<Color>("red");

  return 0;
}
```

(If you are afraid of name-clashes, or generally don't want to put anything in global scope, you can put `to_string` and `from_string` into a namespace `convert` and use them as `convert::from_string<Color>("red")` etc. Or even, create a class template `convert` such that you can call it as `convert<Color>::from_string("red")`, which result in very easy-to-ready, intuitive code.)